# FluentValidation rule for null object

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I've been trying to work out how to create a FluentValidation rule that checks if the instance of an object it's validating is not null, prior to validating it's properties.

I'd rather encapsulate this null validation in the Validator rather then doing it in the calling code.

See example code below with comments where the required logic is needed:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using FluentValidation;

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> 
    {
        public CustomerValidator() 
        {
            // Rule to check the customer instance is not null.

            // Don't continue validating.

            RuleFor(c => c.Surname).NotEmpty();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public void DoCustomerWork(int id)
        {
            var customer = GetCustomer(id);
            var validator = new CustomerValidator();

            var results = validator.Validate(customer);

            var validationSucceeded = results.IsValid;
        }

        public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is **how do I check in the CustomerValidator() constructor that the current instance of customer is not null** and **abort further rule processing if it is null**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Override the `Validate` method?

Comment: So have an extension method that checks if it's null first before calling the base Validate() method?

Comment: No, see my answer below.  You would call it as you would any other validator.

Comment: The latest answer to this is to override the PreValidate() method. Code example below.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**EDIT 2022-07-19**
As some commenters have pointed out, please check out answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52784357/1943 for a newer implementation.  I haven't personally vetted, but it's worth a try to give that a go first.

If you're using an older version, or you enjoy nostalgia, my original answer below is from 2013.

---

You should be able to override the `Validate` method in your `CustomerValidator` class.

```
public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> 
{
    // constructor...
    
    public override ValidationResult Validate(Customer instance)
    {
        return instance == null 
            ? new ValidationResult(new [] { new ValidationFailure("Customer", "Customer cannot be null") }) 
            : base.Validate(instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could even cut it down to this:             
return instance == null 
    ? new ValidationResult(new [] { new ValidationFailure("Customer", "Customer cannot be null") })
    : base.Validate(instance);

Comment: I'm using the latest version of FluentValidation and the Validate() doesn't even fire for me. This doesn't appear to be possible anymore.

Comment: @SergeyAkopov I don't understand how `Validate` doesn't fire since you would be the one calling the validate method.

Comment: This didn't work for me on 6.2.0 as I am calling `ValidateAndThrow` extension method. It blows up before even getting to my overridden `Validate` method..

Comment: @LeeCampbell : Did you find any solution to handle null model in web api ?

Comment: I created another extension method. See answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095791/fluentvalidation-rule-for-null-object/#answer-37289001

Comment: @Matthew, depends entirely on how you use the library. if you explicitly call validate than this will work. If you use WebAPI integration, than having null object will prevent Fluent from discovering the type-specific validator and hence `Validate()` will not be called.

Comment: As of 8.1.3 ([link](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/commit/820e9c3cbbec621c4e2b533cfca79edc6d73148b)), it looks like you can override the `PreValidate()` method if you want to implement custom logic to handle null models that are passed to the validator.

Comment: This solution no longer works for new versions of FluentValidation

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52784357/1943 (override PreValidate()) for updated approach from the developer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated my answer to hopefully save people time and forward to the newer implementation.

Answer (score 32):

I can't really test that right now, but you can either try to override `Validate`, or include the rules in the `When` block:

```
public CustomerValidator()
{
     When(x => x != null, () => {
         RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotEmpty();
         //etc.
     });
}
```

Comment: Nice, but is there a way I can apply a validation message to it, i.e. .WithMessage("Customer does not exist."); ?

Comment: @Bern Maybe you could do `RuleFor(x => x).NotNull().WithMessage("Customer does not exist");`, but outside the `When` block?

Comment: Thanks mate, yeah I tried that and it threw an exception. I think @Matthew managed to nail it above.

Comment: Alright, I guess then that overriding `Validate` is the best way to go here

Answer (score 15):

This is an older post, but want to update the answers to include the following from the FluentValidation documentation:

**Using PreValidate**

If you need to run specific code every time a validator is invoked, you can do this by overriding the PreValidate method. This method takes a ValidationContext as well as a ValidationResult, which you can use to customise the validation process.

```
public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
  public MyValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull();
  }

  protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<Person> context, ValidationResult result) {
    if (context.InstanceToValidate == null) {
      result.Errors.Add(new ValidationFailure("", "Please ensure a model was supplied."));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/advanced.html?#prevalidate

Answer (score 14):

For those using version >6.2.1 you need to override this signature instead, in order to achieve the same as @chrispr:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<T> context)
{
    return (context.InstanceToValidate == null) 
        ? new ValidationResult(new[] { new ValidationFailure("Property", "Error Message") })
        : base.Validate(context);       
}
```

/// EXAMPLE FOR NETCORE-3.1
/// fluentvalidator-9.5.0

```
public class Organisation
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrganisationValidator : AbstractValidator<Organisation>
{
    public OrganisationValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().MaximumLength(50);
    }

    protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<Organisation> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        if (context.InstanceToValidate == null) {
            result.Errors.Add(new ValidationFailure("", "org is null"));
            return false;
        }
        return base.PreValidate(context, result);
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ValidateWithNull()
    {
        var validator = new OrganisationValidator();
        Organisation organisation = null;
        var result = validator.Validate(organisation);
        // result.Errors[0].ErrorMessage == "org is null";
    }
}
```

Comment: This method neither not fired for WebApi.

Comment: @Akin_Glen Could you elaborate? By coincidence I have returned to this answer I edited over 2.5 years ago on the same day you have added your comment. I have this working in a .NetStandard 2.1 class library. The validator used to throw on null input, but returns a ValidationFailure using the above solution

Comment: I'm using version 9.2.0 and basically after registering the validator in my startup, it should automatically pick up instances where an object is null. That doesn't happen with this example, for some reason. I had to use @user7617828's answer for this

Comment: I've tries all examples from this post - none works.

Comment: @AlexBlokha, could you perhaps provide a bit more context of your specific situation? Which framework are you using net45x, netcore?

Comment: .net core 3.1, WebApi. It seems those tricks are not working under WebApi.

Comment: @AlexBlokha, i've updated the example that works for netcore 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

As the above solutions didn't work for me (FluentValidation, Version=6.2.1.0 for Net45), I am posting what I did.
This is just a simple replacement/wrapper for `ValidateAndThrow` extension method.

```
public static class ValidatorExtensions
{
    public static void ValidateAndThrowNotNull<T>(this IValidator<T> validator, T instance)
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            var validationResult = new ValidationResult(new[] { new ValidationFailure("", "Instance cannot be null") });
            throw new ValidationException(validationResult.Errors);
        }
        validator.ValidateAndThrow(instance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Override EnsureInstanceNotNull as below

```
protected override void EnsureInstanceNotNull(object instanceToValidate)
{
    if(instanceToValidate==null)
      throw new ValidationException("Customer can not be null");
}
```

Comment: Overriding this method is the "official" approach as explained here:
https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/486

Comment: When is this method running? Before the ValidateMethod?

Comment: This metod is running after validation and only if object is not null :). Version 8.6.3

Answer (score 3):

By means of Custom(). It can be also very helpful when validation of another field is based on validation of your current field.

```
ruleBuilder.Custom((obj, context) =>
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                var propertyName = <field where should be validation>;
                context.AddFailure(propertyName, "'Your field name' Your validation message.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works. I would implore everyone to implement this. If you have an object in your model and you need fluent validator to send an error message if that object is omitted when your API is called, this is how it should be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I inherited from the fluent AbstractValidator and created a NullReferenceAbstractValidator class instead:

```
public class NullReferenceAbstractValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(T instance)
    {
        return instance == null
            ? new ValidationResult(new[] { new ValidationFailure(instance.ToString(), "response cannot be null","Error") })
            : base.Validate(instance);
    }
}
```

and then inherited from that class with each validator that needed a null reference check:

```
public class UserValidator : NullReferenceAbstractValidator<User>
```

Comment: why are you doing instance.ToString() when instance is null?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Cascade mode.

Here is the example from the [documentation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/d.-Configuring-a-Validator#setting-the-cascade-mode).

```
RuleFor(x => x.Surname).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).NotNull().NotEqual("foo");
```

Also from the documentation:

> If the NotNull validator fails then the NotEqual validator will not be
>   executed. This is particularly useful if you have a complex chain
>   where each validator depends on the previous validator to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can override a virtual method called EnsureInstanceNotNull as the author recommends [here](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/486#issuecomment-308075903)

```
public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> 
{
    public CustomerValidator() 
    {
        // Rule to check the customer instance is not null.
        RuleFor(c => c).NotNull();
        // Don't continue validating.

        RuleFor(c => c.Surname).NotEmpty();
    }

    protected override void EnsureInstanceNotNull(object instance) { }
}
```

Comment: If you are reading this in the year of our lord 2024, the `EnsureInstanceNotNull` is deprecated.  Instead override the `PreValidate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

[The commonly accepted PreValidate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095791/fluentvalidation-rule-for-null-object/52784357#52784357) will not work in this instance, as per [here](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/582):

> If you use SetValidator with an AbstractValidator derivative, then it
> will not be run if the property value is null. This is intentional
> behaviour as AbstractValidator derivatives are designed to validate
> the properties of a complex type, which cannot be done if the instance
> is null. AbstractValidator is not designed for use with
> simple/primative types or object. Now, if you want to check for null
> here, then you can precede the SetValidator call with a NotNull rule
> (although it doesn't seem like this is what you want in this case).

For me the only thing that worked is (my example):

```
RuleForEach(command => command.ProductDto.ProductInfos).NotNull().WithMessage("Custom Message").SetValidator(new ProductInfoValidator());
```

Without the "NotNull()", null values will be skipped.